# Ansible Tower can't find my roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I have my directory structure setup such that the playbooks directory is under `/var/lib/awx/projects/` and roles is a symlink under playbooks.

I need symlinks for roles as I'm using git push from my local system to push `playbooks/roles` to Tower and both playbooks and roles are under a different git repo.

When I try to run a job in Tower, it complains that it can't find my roles. When I look at every path that ansible states that it has looked in, they are there.

Any ideas why my roles can't be found?

Answer (score 2):

If the symlinks indeed are the problem (I can't tell) then [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) might be a solution for you. You could add your "roles" repository as a submodule to the repository where the playbooks are located. You need to clone the parent repository then recursive:

```
git clone --recursive playbooks
```

Be aware submodules can be a huge PITA, but if you are required to have playbooks and roles in separate repositories and symlinks are indeed not followed by tower, this might be a solution.

---

Another solution would be to create a separate git repository for every role. Then you could install each role separately via [ansible-galaxy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#advanced-control-over-role-requirements-files). For that you need a `requirements.yml` with all your roles defined like this:

```
 - src: https://gitsource.host/user/some_role
   version: master
   name: some_role
```

Ansible Tower would install all listed roles automatically, as described [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/2.4.1/html/userguide/overview.html#ansible-galaxy-integration).